# Exporting Java Source to JAR file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

When Exporting the Source code folder to JAR file in Eclipse it is getting exported with some warnings

When the exported JAR file is decompiled and checked , there are some class files which when opened showing error message like

```
  "Invalid class file <fileName.class>: Can not read buffer"
```

What are the possible reasons for this problem and how to avoid that

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2 )

Comment: Have you attempted to manually compile the program and test the creation of the Jar outside of Eclipse? `jar cvf testJar.jar *` I have not seen that specific error but it seems like it is possible your files aren't compiled or imported correctly

Comment: How do you decompile those classes?

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to export jar file from eclipse follow following step:

1. **File-> Export**
2. **Select following checkboxes and destination folder.**

[image]

3. **Now again deselect following checkboxes.**

[image]

4. **Select like this image.**

[image]

5. **Then finish.**
6. **Goto to folder where you saved jar file and run java -jar jarname.jar**
7. Then you can decompile jar file using JD GUI and check your classes are decompiled correctly or not.